# TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable with CoreMLTools

Tags: swift, keras, coremltools

I'm trying to convert a VGG model to coremltools. When I run the following code to convert the model:

```
with CustomObjectScope({'relu6': keras.layers.ReLU,'DepthwiseConv2D': keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D}):
    from keras.models import load_model
    import coremltools


model_directory = 'KerasModels/VGG-7-3-20_13categories.h5'

keras_model = load_model(model_directory)
input_layer = InputLayer(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), name="input_1")

# Save and convert :
keras_model.layers[0] = input_layer
keras_model.save(model_directory)
print("Changed2")


your_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model_directory, input_names=['image'], output_names=['output'], image_input_names='image')




your_model.save('RecycleNet.mlmodel')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable
```

How should I go about converting this model to coremltools? Thanks

Comment: because there is no such layer named InputLayer but Input does.

Comment: I changed it to Input but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by switching from using:

```
coremltools.converters.keras
```

to:

```
coremltools.converters.tensorflow
```

Answer (score -1):

This line of code solved for me:

```
coremlModel = coremltools.convert(model)
```

instead of using this:

```
coremlModel = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
```