# Error converting keras model to coreml ('InputLayer' object is not iterable)

Tags: keras, converters, coreml

my keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(18, 63)))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y,  batch_size=30, verbose=2, epochs=90,validation_split=0.2)
```

I try convert model to coreml:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
    model,
    input_names=['input'],
    output_names=["output"])
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable
```

**Update:**

With

```
coreml_model = coremltools.convert(...)
```

I get this error(here is an incomplete error code)

```
InvalidArgumentError: Attempting to add a duplicate function with name: while_cond_45890 where the previous and current definitions differ. Previous definiton: signature {
  name: "while_cond_45890"
  input_arg {
    name: "while_while_loop_counter"
    type: DT_INT32
  }
  input_arg {
    name: "while_while_maximum_iterations"
    type: DT_INT32
  }
....
```

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719352/typeerror-inputlayer-object-is-not-iterable-with-coremltools) might help.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help

Comment: I'm getting the same error, let me know if you manage to fix it

Comment: I decided to use the tflite model. It didn't work any other way

Comment: So did you convert your Keras model to tflite or did you rewrite the whole model there?

Comment: i converted Keras model to tflite

Answer (score 0):

Is this model made with tf.keras or standalone Keras? If tf.keras, you shouldn't use the Keras converter but the unified conversion API, `coremltools.convert(...)`

Comment: I tried your version, but got another error